# CSS display inline-flex not correctly lined up in some devices

Tags: html, css

I have a website with some HTML code that is displayed differently according to the device, even when using Google Chrome in all of them.

This is how it is displayed in one of them:

[image]

As you can see inside the red circle the text is not properly lined up. So it should be like in the following screenshot (taken with another device):

[image]

In this case, the character 私 is lined up with the other characters of the same font size.

And this is a snippet, where you might see it as image (1) or (2) depending on your device.

```css
.markdownContainer {
    padding: .5rem;
    word-break: break-word;
}

.example {
    border: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.15rem;
}

.mdContainer {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: .35rem;
    margin: 1rem .5rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.kanji {
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    text-align: center;
}

.kanji>span {
    font-size: .5rem;
    margin-bottom: -.25rem;
}

.example>.kanji>span {
    font-size: .7rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="mdContainer example"><span class="kanji">私<span>わたし</span></span>はスペイン<span class="kanji">人<span>じん</span></span><span class="primary">だ</span><br>I am Spanish</div>

<div class="markdownContainer">Number + <span class="kanji">時<span>じ</span></span><br><span class="kanji">半<span>はん</span></span> can be appended to indicate "and a half"</div>
```

It is not working in the following devices:

> Operating System: Android 10
>
> Google Chrome version: 108.0.5359.128

> Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04 (no updates available, at least for Chrome)
>
> Google Chrome version: 108.0.5359.124

The one where it's working:

> Google Chrome version: Chrome 107.0.5304.105
>
> Operating System: Android 13

But it's also working in Chrome of Iphone devices for example (can't check the version since I don't have, but I had the change to check it and it was okay).

My only guess is one update of google chrome broke it, and the devices where it does not work it's because they are not updated yet. But I checked the changelog of chrome and couldn't find anything, so I wonder if the code is actually correct or not.

Any ideas what could be going on?

EDIT: I updated the question to add another type of container with the same issue. You can see it also in here https://www.fluento.net/jp/N5/grammar/card/number-%E6%99%82

Since the string with the information comes as a String with some custom markdown, I have no easy way of adding `span` around the normal text. So if there is a way to do it without setting `display: flex` I would prefer doing it that way.

Answer (score 0):

You are never aligning your elements to the bottom; therefore, by default, elements try to take up the space that's already available (i.e., space at the top of the page). You need to make a `flex` and align the items as such:

CSS:

```css
.example {
    border: 0;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.15rem;
}
    
.mdContainer {
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: .35rem;
    margin: 1rem .5rem;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.kanji {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
    text-align: center;
}

.kanji>span {
    font-size: .5rem;
    margin-bottom: -.25rem;
}

.example>.kanji>span {
    font-size: .7rem;
}
```

HTML:

```html
<div class="mdContainer example">
    <div class="container">
        <span class="kanji">私<span>わたし</span></span>
        <span>はスペイン</span>
        <span class="kanji">人<span>じん</span></span>
        <span class="primary">だ</span>
    </div>
    
    <span>I am Spanish</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any way of achieveing this without flexbox? It breaks all other containers. For instance, the How To section at: https://www.fluento.net/jp/N5/grammar/card/number-%E6%99%82. And adding a span like that is not an option, since the code comes formatted from a string in MongoDB. I updated the question, with a bigger example (which I was trying to avoid to not bloat it)

Comment: This is not working correctly. To begin with, there is no easy way to make a line break with flexbox, so the `<br>` tags are completely ignored. And second, if there is a `<span>something </span>` the last whitespace is ignored. And there is no easy way to center some text, and other not (for example the text inside an example container should be centered, but the one outside no)

Comment: @lpares12 in the example, I haven't used `br`. You have to make `container` as `flex` not the `mdContainer`. Please refer to the example.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I went with the usage of the [ruby](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ruby) HTML. It does not directly resolve the question, but it solves my issue.

Leaving the question open in case someone can figure out how to properly do this without the ruby tag.

https://www.w3.org/TR/css-ruby-1/#default-ua-ruby